# Some really tricky concepts that need to be cleared up in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ (the set of $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}[x]$), and the vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$. Now let $k>0$ be the smallest integer such that the set of vectors $\{v,Av,A^2v,\ldots,A^kv\}$ is linearly dependent.

Let us now define
$$V= \operatorname{Span}(\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{k-1}v\}).$$
How do we show that this set of vectors spanning $V$ is a basis $\mathcal{B}$? Well, to be a basis for some vector space, we require that the set of vectors span that vector space, which in this case, they do **and** that the set of vectors be linearly independent. This is where one of my difficulties arises: how is it that $\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{k-1}v\}$ is linearly independent, while $\{v,Av,\ldots,A^kv\}$ is not?

Next, suppose we let the transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ be induced by multiplication by $A$, i.e. $T(w)= Aw$ for $w \in V$. How exactly do we find the coordinate matrix $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$? I don't quite remember how to do this. I would guess that it would be something like this, but I'm not sure:
$$ [w|Aw|\cdots|A^{k-1}w]_{\mathcal{B}}. $$
Where do I go from here?

Finally, I know that the annihilator of $v$ w.r.t. $A$ given as the set
$$\{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(v)=0\},$$ 
is an ideal in $\mathbb{F}[x]$. But if I define the annihilator of the vector space $V$ w.r.t. $A$ as
$$\{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(w)=0 \forall w \in V\},$$ 
wouldn't both annihilators be the same? If so, how? I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: @joriki: Never mind: I misread it.

Comment: @Sachin: $\{v,Av,\dotsc,A^{k−1}v\}$ is linearly independent because if it were linearly dependent $k$ wouldn't be the smallest integer such that $\{v,Av,\dotsc,A^kv\}$ is linearly dependent.

Likewise, $\{v,Av,\dotsc,A^kv\}$ isn't linearly independent because if it were, $k$ wouldn't be the smallest integer such that $\{v,Av,\dotsc,A^kv\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: You should either require $v\ne 0$ or only expect $k$ to be $\ge0$ (instead of $>0$). Otherwise it might happen that $\{v, \ldots A^{k-1}v\}=\{0\}$ is linearly dependant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\mathcal{B}=\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{k-1}v\}$. Set $v_{i+1}=A^iv\;\;\;\forall i \in \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$. So we have $Av_i=v_{i+1}\;\;\forall i=1,2,\ldots k-1$

By definition $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}=(a_{i,j})$ is the matrix with

\begin{split}
T(v_1)&=a_{1,1}v_1+a_{2,1}v_2+\ldots+a_{k,1}v_k\\
T(v_2)&=a_{1,2}v_1+a_{2,2}v_2+\ldots+a_{k,2}v_k\\
\vdots\;\;&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\
T(v_k)&=a_{1,k}v_1+a_{2,k}v_2+\ldots+a_{k,k}v_k\\
\end{split}

Since $T(v_i)=Av_i=v_{i+1}\;\;\forall i=1,2,\ldots k-1$ we deduce that the first k-1 columns of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ are the vectors $e_{i+1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
1 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}\ , $
the $1$ being in the ${i+1}^{th}$ position, respectively. The last column of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is calculated by the definition of $k$. By the definition of $k$ we have that

$T(v_{k})=A^kv=c_1v+c_2Av+\ldots+c_kA^{k-1}v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\ldots+c_kv_k$

for some $c_i\in \mathbb{F}$, so the last column of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ will be 
$\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\ 
c_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
c_k
\end{pmatrix}\ . $

For your third question the answer is yes the two annihilators will be the same since:

i) if $h\in \{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(w)=0 \forall w \in V\} \Longrightarrow h(A)(v)=0 $

so

$$h \in \{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(v)=0\} \ .$$

ii) if $h \in \{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(v)=0\} \Longrightarrow h(A)(v)=0$.

Observe that $h(A)(A^iv)=(hx^i)(A)(v)=(x^ih)(A)(v)=A^i(h(A)(v))=0\;\;\forall\; i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Using the fact that $V= Span(\{v,Av,…,A^{k-1}v\})$  we deduce

$$h \in \{g \in \mathbb{F}[x]: g(A)(v)=0\} \ .$$

Comment: Wouldn't the $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$?

Comment: @Sachin: Yes $c_i\in \mathbb{F}$. I corrected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

joriki already answered your first question.

For your second question, you know that $v, Av, \dots, A^k v$ are linearly dependent, so that there are $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_k \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $c_0 v + c_1 Av + \cdots + c_k A^k v = 0$.  Now $c_k \neq 0$ (otherwise $v, Av, \dots, A^{k-1} v$ would be linearly dependent), so we may divide the equation by $c_k$ and therefore assume $c_k = 1$.

Let's describe your basis as $w_1 = v, w_2 = Av, \dots, w_k = A^{k-1} v$.  Then we have, for $1 \leq i \leq k-1$,
$$
A(w_i) = A(A^{i-1}(v)) = A^i(v) = w_{i+1}.
$$
For $i = k$, we must use the linear dependency:
$$
\begin{align*}
A(w_k) = A(A^{k-1}(v)) = A^k(v) & = -c_0 v - c_1 Av - \dots - c_{k-1} A^{k-1}v \\ & = -c_0 w_1 - c_1 w_2 - \cdots - c_{k-1} w_k.
\end{align*}
$$

For your last question, notice that the annihilator of the vector $v = 0$ wrt $A$ is always $\langle x \rangle$, the ideal generated by $x$.  But the annihilator of $V$ wrt $A$ is never $\langle x \rangle$ unless $A = 0$ (edit: or $V = 0$).

Edit: As pambos pointed out, the question about annihilators refers to $v$ and $V$ as defined earlier.  In that case, the annihilator of $v$ *is* the annihilator of $V$.  If you assume that $p(x)$ is in the annihilator of $v$, i.e. $p(A)(v) = 0$, then it follows that $p(A)(A^i v) = A^i(p(A)(v)) = 0$, so each $p(A)$ annihilates each $A^i v$ and thus annihilates $V$.

Comment: @micheal can you please explain, in what ring are we considering the ideal?

Comment: @PhaniRaj: In the ring $\mathbb{F}[x]$ of polynomials in one variable with coefficients in the given field $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: For the annihilator, if $v=0$ then $V=\{0\}$ so the two annihilators are the same.

Comment: @Pambos: No, $v = 0$ is in every vector space $V$, not just the zero vector space.  The annihilator of a single vector wrt a linear transformation is a different concept than the annihilator of a vector space wrt a linear transformation.  (Perhaps what you are getting at is that the annihilator of a vector $v$ is the same as the annihilator of the vector space $\text{Span}(v)$, but not every vector space is the span of a single vector!)

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: Correct, but in our case $V=\operatorname{Span}(\{v,Av,\ldots\})$ and the question is if the annihilator of $v$ is the same as the annihilator of $V$.

Comment: @Pambos: Oh yes, I interpreted the third question independently of the first two, but of course your interpretation is much more sensible!

Answer (score 3):

1. Since $F^n$ has dimension $n$, any $n+1$ vectors are linearly dependent, so are $v,Av,A^2v,\dots,A^nv$. So, there must exist a least integer $k$ as it is said above. So the answer on your first question is: by def. of $k$.
2. $\mathcal B$ denotes the basis $\langle v,Av,..A^{k-1}v\rangle$ (for a tuple of vectors being a basis in the space they  span  is equivalent to being linearly independent).
   Then the columns of $[A]_{\mathcal B}$ are the $A$ images of the basis elements, in the given order, the images written into coordinates according to $\mathcal B$.