# Follow-up question regarding a cyclic basis with computations in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a follow-up homework question(s) to a conceptual question I had asked earlier with regard to the cyclic basis of the vector space  $V$ denoted by $\mathcal{B}= \{v,Av,…,A^{k-1}v\}$, where $A \in M_n(F)$, and $v \in F^n$. Also, there is a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ which is basically matrix multiplication by $A$, i.e. $T(v)= Av$. The question is as follows:

We are asked to find the explicit basis $\mathcal{B}$ for the module $V = F[x]v$, and the minimal polynomial $f= \min_{T}(x)$ for $T$ given specific choices for $A$ and $v$. We are also asked to find the coordinate matrix $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$.

$1$. $A = \begin{bmatrix}12&2&3&-7\\ -5&2&-2&4\\6&1&5&-5\\13&3&4&-7\end{bmatrix}$, $F= \mathbb{Q}$, $v = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-1\\ 
-1\\
\
-1
\end{bmatrix}.$

$2$. $A= \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta  \end{bmatrix}$, $0< \theta < 2\pi$, $F= \mathbb{R}$, $v= e_1$.

$3$. $A= \begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0\\ 0&3&0\\ 0&0&4  \end{bmatrix}$, $F= \mathbb{Q}$, $v= e_1+ e_2$.

$4$. $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$, $F= \mathbb{Z}_2$, $v= e_1$.

Well, for all of these, I computed the bases via matrix multiplication by $A, A^2,…, A^{k-1}$ with $v$ first. Is that the right approach? Does finding the minimal polynomial $f$ of the transformation $T$ require finding the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (which I already found), but what next? Finally, is the coordinate matrix $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ the companion matrix $C(f)$ of $f$?

Comment: I think for the third problem, the minimal polynomial is just the product $(x-2)(x-3)= x^2 -5x +6$ since we're dealing in two dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part:

the matrix $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. As you said you form the vectors $\{ v,A\cdot v,\ldots,A^i\cdot v\}$ but you have to stop in that minimal $i\leq n$ such that $A^{i+1}\cdot v$ is a linear combination of $\{ v,A\cdot v,\ldots,A^i\cdot v\}$. Your $k$ is my $i-1$.

For the other parts:

yes the coordinate matrix $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ is the companion matrix $C(f)$ of $f$. We explained how to calculate the matrix $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ in your question [Some really tricky concepts that need to be cleared up in linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203145/some-really-tricky-concepts-that-need-to-be-cleared-up-in-linear-algebra/204506#204506) 
so, that and the first part of this question can help you find the minimal polynomial $f$ of $T$.

e.g. for $3.$ we have:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&4
\end{pmatrix}
$
and $v=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$
so

$$v=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
Av=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
3\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
A^2v=\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
9\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and $A^2v=(-6)v+5Av \ . $

Thus $[T]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-6\\
1&5
\end{pmatrix}$.

This is the companion matrix of $f$ so (as you correctly noticed) 
$$f(x)=x^2-5x+6=(x-3)(x-2) \ .$$